# Need help writing a routing rule

Tags: networking, routing

My 14.04 LTS ubuntu box has 2 active network connections. the default gateway is the hardwired eth0 (192.168.1.x) going to my cable modem.

The wireless connection (wlan0 at 192.168.0.x)  is to a cellular access point to Sprint LTE gateway, and I want to ssh with the -b option to bind to the wireless connection and with socks proxy port forwarding going through the Sprint network, not through my cable modem. (I couldn't figure out how to run a separate 2nd sshd process for the wireless connection)

What routing rules are required to route the ssh socks proxy traffic through the wireless connection rather than the default gateway on eth0?

Comment: I think you might need to create a second gateway and attach wlan0 interface to it so it won't automatically go through your default gateway which is the cable modem. Can you paste the output of the `route` command?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I tried to paste the output of "route", but it takes out newlines.  Trying to figure a way around this....

Comment: Kernel IP routing table                                                         
    Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface   
    default         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0    
    192.168.0.0     192.168.0.46    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 wlan0   
    192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0   
    192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

Comment: I'm at a loss on how to avoid the prior reformatting. Anyway, I had attempted to create a 2nd gateway with this command:  route add -net 192.168.0.0/24 gw 192.168.0.46

Comment: You can edit your original post. Try `route -n` and update your OP because that's somewhat confusing.